# MS ACCESS - How to create a Query with SQL Command?

Tags: ms-access

I know how to create a **Query** though **Query Design** (manually)

[image]

but how to create a "**Query**" with **command**? 
i am looking for something like

```
Create Query [Query_Name] 
As
Select * from Table1
```

Can anyone post me the code snippet that can do something like this?

### **Things i have TRIED**

1. **Erik von Asmuth's solution** : The below query

   CREATE PROCEDURE MyQuery
   [@Param1] Integer;
   SELECT *
   FROM SalesInvoice
   WHERE SalesInvoice.S_Id = [@Param1]

gave the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PROCEDURE` command. Since Access doesn't have stored procedures, that just creates a query.

E.g.:

```sql
PROCEDURE MyQuery
[@Param1] Integer;
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.ID = [@Param1]
```

The use case is pretty limited, since queries are usually created through VBA using the `CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef` method.

Comment: i have tried it and it didnt work, for more detail see the updated question

Comment: You haven't executed it through ADO, which is necessary for it to work

Comment: can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Search VBA help for `CREATE PROCEDURE`, it has an example.